# JMX MBeanServer.queryMBeans with Query exp does not work

Tags: java, jmx

I'd like to use MBeanServer.queryMBeans(ObjectName name, QueryExp query) to get MBeans with query expression, but it seems it does not really work with QueryExp query. For example I have such test code:

```
public class CreateAndRegisterMBeanInMBeanServer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String objectName = "com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise:type=Hello";
    QueryExp exp = Query.eq(Query.attr("type"), Query.value("Hello"));


    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

    // Construct the ObjectName for the Hello MBean we will register
    ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName(objectName);

    Hello mbean = new Hello();

    server.registerMBean(mbean, mbeanName);

    Set<ObjectInstance> instances = server.queryMBeans(new ObjectName(objectName), null);
    System.out.println(instances.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < instances.size(); i++) {
        ObjectInstance instance = (ObjectInstance) instances.toArray()[i];

        System.out.println("Class Name:t" + instance.getClassName());
        System.out.println("Object Name:t" + instance.getObjectName());
    }

}

static class Hello implements HelloMBean {

    private String message = "Hello World";

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}

static interface HelloMBean {

    // operations

    public void sayHello();

    // attributes

    // a read-write attribute called Message of type String
    public String getMessage();

    public void setMessage(String message);

}
```

}

I can get expected out:
1
Class Name:tCreateAndRegisterMBeanInMBeanServer$Hello
Object Name:tcom.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise:type=Hello

But if I change my code to use defined QueryExp exp as:

Set instances = server.queryMBeans(new ObjectName(objectName), exp);

I can not see any selected MBean, Is that the correct way to use such Query Exp ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
QueryExp exp = Query.eq(Query.attr("type"), Query.value("Hello"));
```

to

```
QueryExp exp = Query.eq(Query.attr("Message"), Query.value("Hello World"));
```

Since type "type" is not an attribute.
Alternatively, if you are trying to query by "type," which is part of the `ObjectName`, you can construct the object name like so:

```
String objectName = "*:type=Hello";
```

Then make the query as before:

```
Set<ObjectInstance> instances = server.queryMBeans(new ObjectName(objectName), null);
```

Comment: perfect ref url...